# iOS skipping login view with rootViewController causing black bar bug in nested TableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6.3, rootview

I'm skipping my initial view controller (a login page) once a user successfully logs into my app and chooses to store their credentials.

My new root view controller is a TabBarController because my app's navigation uses a TabBar.

However, within the application I have TableViews that are preceded by their respective NavigationController. In these TableViews I am getting a black bar above the TabBar. If I navigate to the next TableView then the black bar doubles, and if I go into the following TableView then the black bar is now 3 times the size of the first.

Here are some screenshots; because of sensitive data I have added gray bars to mask the live data.

[image: First Bar]

[image: Double Sized Bar after second navigation to TableView]

[image: Third navigation to TableView, now 3 times initial size]

I have this in my AppDelegate (using Swift) in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
    if let api_key = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("key") {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarC") as! MyTabBarController
        if let window = self.window {
            window.rootViewController = tabBarController
        }
    }
```

Should I be instantiating the inner Navigation Controllers? If so, how do i do this since my TabBar already has 4 NavigationControllers for the 4 tabs, where would I insert the additional NavControllers found deep within the application?

**UPDATE:**
I was able to resolve the black bar bug by

1. closing the project
2. compressing the Main.storyboard file to keep as backup
3. removed the Main.storyboard file from the project folder
4. added back in a previous version of Main.storyboard from a backup

I also found an alternative way to "skip" my login screen without needing to instantiate view controllers in my app delegate.

**psuedo code**
In storyboard add an ID to the segue between the login and tabBar view controller.

```
In the login VC
    view did load
        hide the textboxes

    if key exists {
        performSegue(id: <segwayid>
    } else {
        show the login textboxes
```

Comment: "4 NavigationControllers for the 4 tabs". You already have 4 and you still want more. Sounds like your entire design needs redoing.

Comment: The nested TableViews are context dependent hence the need of the nesting. e.g. First tab is for projects and following nested tableview shows tasks for the particular project that was selected.

Comment: Does the Time Entries screen have its own navigationController, or is it placed within the same one the previous screen was using?

Comment: Each of these views has their own navigation controller

Comment: Are you setting the storyboard in project setting? + Set the root view controller to the main tab bar. not to one of the tab bars.

Comment: No I have not modified any settings in the project settings. The tabBarController that I set as the rootViewController is the tabBar itself and not the tab items.

Answer (score 0):

O.K, In your project settings. do not set the main storyboard.

[image: ProjectSeetings]

and change your code to the following:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var rootController = nil

if let api_key = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("key") {
    rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarC") as! MyTabBarController
        } 
else {
    rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginController") as! LoginController // Change this line according to your project.
}

self.window!.rootViewController = rootController
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: In the last if statement did you mean to set window.rootViewController = tabBarController? Or to the rootController that you've defined and are conditionally setting

Comment: I tried this and now I get a completely black screen when the app launches. I have resolved the problem by replacing my Main.storyboard file with a backup prior to the black bars. Is it possible that there was some corruption in my Main.storyboard file? does that happen?

Comment: @MaryMartinez no, just call make key and visible on window.

Comment: this works now to display the screens but the black bar issue is still there. Thanks for your help though! I am going to to update the question with an alternative solution that I found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that you change each `view's frame` to not go under the `UITabBar` by code.

You should review your `loadView` (if so), `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` method in you `UIViewController`.